# how can i finding the index of non-ASCII character in python string?

Tags: python, regex, string, search, range

Python has string.find() and string.rfind() to get the index of a substring in string.

And re.search(regex,string) to get the 'first index' of a substring in string. but, this function is return to match object :(

So i wonder, merge the two function. by a regex to check for the string and return the first index. (index is not match object type :b)

example :

```
string = "abcdeÿÿaaaabbbÿÿcccdddÿÿeeeÿÿ"
print custom(string)
```

result :

```
>>> 5
```

non-ASCII range is [^\x20-\x7E], how does implementation this function??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use this 2 function use the first group of `re.search` within `find` :

```
>>> g = "abcdeÿÿaaaabbbÿÿcccdddÿÿeeeÿÿ"
>>> import re
>>> g.find(re.search(r'[^\x20-\x7E]',g).group(0))
5
```

But if you just want to find the index `re.search` has the `start` method that return the index of matched string :

```
>>> re.search(r'[^\x20-\x7E]',g).start()
5
```

Also you can do it without regex :

```
>>> import string
>>> next(i for i,j in enumerate(g) if j not in string.ascii_letters)
5
```

Answer (score 2):

"MatchObjects" have a [`start`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.start) method you can use:

```
import re

def custom(s):
    mat = re.search(r'[^\x20-\x7E]', s)
    if mat: return mat.start()
    return -1  # ?? match failed

string = "abcdeÿÿaaaabbbÿÿcccdddÿÿeeeÿÿ"
print(custom(string))  # 5
```